# Scrape dinamically generated content from Oddsportal with Python + requests

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, ajax, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the content of a profile like this one [Oddsportal](https://www.oddsportal.com/profile/petersson1984/my-predictions/next/) with requests

In it, everything can be easily obtained doing the following, except for the betting odds at which the tip was recorded.

```
response=requests.get(url='https://www.oddsportal.com/profile/petersson1984/my-predictions/next/')
```

[image: Dinamic]

If you search in the source code with `Ctrl+U` you can see that the tags in which this information is later on added are empty, but you can also see some unique ids
[image: Xeid]

At the bottom of the source code there is a script in which those ids are also located, and I assume what it does is call a JS function in the global JS call
[image: JS]

The thing is, I've looked in every call, XHR, JS, or DOC in order to find, for example, `1.97`. It isn't. My guess is that somehow the data from the script in the source code is transformed or there is a second call, but I'm not proficient with JS calls and I'm unable to understand what is been done and how to get the odds highlighed in the first picture from above.